# Select Statement to return TaskID if column Exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

First table is called task the second table is named countries.

My task table

```
                 ID    TaskID   Country         CustomerID
                 ------------------------------------------
                 1     213      china               22
                 2     213      USA                 24
                 3     213      china               26
                 4     214      Canada              28
```

Countries table

```
           ID  Country
           ---------------
           1  USA
           2  Japan
           3  England
```

I need a select statement  that returns all task ID's that doesnt have its country i the countries table.
In this case I would need to return TASKID: 214 because canada is not in the countries table. I would not get TASKID: 213 because USA is in the countries table.

Comment: China is not in the countries table either

Comment: I know as long as one of the countries with the same TaskID is not in that table i need to return that TaskID

Comment: Suppose if a single task Id has multiple countries then all the countries should exist in countries table otherwise you wont need that taskid. Is n't it?

Comment: My actual country table has 12 countries that are deemed prohibited for my requirement. If i did it that way, i would have to list every country in the world in the country table except the 12 prohibited countries.  I need to find which taskID has a prohibited country in the country table.  My actual task table is larger than this i just simplified it on here.

Comment: Your question and your comment is violating. Please edit your question.

Comment: How is is violating so i can fix it. I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   TaskID
FROM
   Task T LEFT OUTER JOIN Countries C ON (T.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY)
GROUP BY
    TaskID
HAVING
    COUNT(C.ID) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   select taskid 
    from task where taskid not in
                  (select taskid from task where country in
                          (select country from countries))
```

Comment: Country is probably nvarchar or varchar, so its not the best way to do it, since it is prone to human error. Should add a countryId column to the task table and compare that to the Id of the countries table, since it is probably the primary key

Comment: This doesnt work form me.  I need to find which taskID has a country in the country table. If a taskID of 213 if that country of any row is in the countries table i need htat taskid

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT t.taskid
FROM task t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM countries
        WHERE country = t.country
        )
```